# What is the difference between Chrome TTS, Google TTS, Cloud Speech API, and Android TTS?

Tags: android, google-chrome-extension, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech, google-cloud-speech

Chrome TTS: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tts

Google TTS: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.tts&hl=en

Cloud Speech API: https://cloud.google.com/speech/

Android TTS: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html

I'm sure there is probably more that I am missing. Ultimately I want to figure out what engine is behind "Okay Google", and see whether that technology exists off the cloud. Figuring out the difference between google's offerings would be a good first start.

Answer (score 3):

*"Cloud Speech API"* is the only one converting speech to text. All the others convert text to speech.

*"Chrome TTS"* is for the Chrome browser, *"Android TTS"* is the API to use text-to-speech in Android apps and *"Google TTS"* is a TTS engine which can be used via the *"Android TTS"* API.

> Ultimately I want to figure out what engine is behind "Okay Google",
>   and see whether that technology exists off the cloud.

Then have a look at the [SpeechRecognizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) documentation.

The `SpeechRecognizer` documentation says:

> The implementation of this API is likely to stream audio to remote
>   servers to perform speech recognition. As such this API is not
>   intended to be used for continuous recognition, which would consume a
>   significant amount of battery and bandwidth.

So it might still require and use the internet access and isn't completely "off the cloud".